# Правильное форматирование выходной строки в Oracle

Tags: sql, строки, oracle

Вот таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
    id integer not null,
    name char(1) not null,
    parent_id integer,
    sum integer not null);

INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(1, 'A', null, 300);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(11, 'B', 1, 2340);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(111, 'C', 11, 3200);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(22, 'D', 1, 7540);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(2, 'E', null, 6300);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(3, 'F', 2, 8600);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(101, 'G', 3, 3800);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(102, 'H', 3, 9700);`
```

Вот код:

```
SELECT sys_connect_by_path(name, ',') as Common
FROM test_table
START WITH parent_id is null
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id`
```

Он выдает иерархическую вложенность имен. Как изменить код, чтобы он показывал только те строки, которые имеют `parent_id`, при этом показывались `name` только `parent_id`, исключая `id` строки?

Comment: У вас начало у запроса куда то пропало. в текущем варианте никаких id оно не выводит. И лучше покажите явно как должен выглядеть желаемый результат

Comment: А строки которые имеют parent_id, это видимо те, которые не на корню дерева ... тогда `WHERE level>1`

Comment: в текущем варианте запрос выводит вложенные name в зависимости от того, есть ли предок у соответствующей строки. Т.е. вывод примерно такой: ,A; ,A,B; ,A,B,C. А нужен вывод типа: ' '; A; A,B. Другими словами, нужно показать, каких предков имеет данная строка.

Comment: Т.е. тот же полный путь sys_connect только как бы предыдущего уровня ?

Comment: Получается, что так. Формально, нужно удалять последние два символа в выходной строке+первую запятую

Comment: первую запятую боюсь только `substr(sys_connect_by_path(name, ','),2)`

Comment: Да, спасибо. Это именно то, что нужно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ключевое слово `prior` обозначающее данные с предыдущего уровня рекурсии работает не только с полями, но и с вычисляемыми значениями и функциями:

```
 select PRIOR sys_connect_by_path(name, ',') as Common
   from test_table
  WHERE level>1     -- Если нам не нужны корневые строки
  START WITH parent_id is null
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id
```

Еще один вариант решения без использования PRIOR в селекте:

`select replace(substr(sys_connect_by_path(name, ','),2), name, '' ) as Common
       from test_table
      WHERE level>1     -- Если нам не нужны корневые строки
      START WITH parent_id is null
    CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id`